# Is there a way to get rid of this tiny space between widgets within a Column?

Tags: flutter, mobile, widget

There is very minimal vertical spacing between widgets in my Column. Is there a way to get rid of it? I have tried to set margins to 0 on both Containers but the spacing remains.
[image: Widget Spacing] [image: Widget Spacing Zoomed In]

```
Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                expanded = !expanded;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              height: 50,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  const Text("Menu", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                  Icon(expanded ? Icons.arrow_drop_up : Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          expanded
              ? Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 40,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                  child: const Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Text("ITEM 1")))
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: I ran your code on web but can not see the said padding/margin. What OS are you running your app on?

Comment: Can't repro on iOS either

Comment: Running it on an android emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was not reproducible on iOS, Web or MacOS but only on Android. I tried `MediaQuery.removePadding` but that did not give me a solution (same behaviour, there's a very subtle line dividing the two containers).

I don't know if you'd accept this as an answer, but you could use an `ExpansionTile` for your case, as it has the exact same behaviour without the dividing line in between.

```
ExpansionTile(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        collapsedBackgroundColor: Colors.red,
        collapsedTextColor: Colors.black,
        textColor: Colors.black,
        iconColor: Colors.black,
        collapsedIconColor: Colors.black,
        title: const Text('hello'),
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 40,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                    child: const Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text("ITEM 1"))),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

You can also change the trailing icon and its rotation by using the `trailing` property of `ExpansionTile`.